# Google Sheets QUERY() and FILTER () NOT WORKING

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a sheet where I use a date selector to query different data sets, so for example:
Start Date: 01.01.2021
End Date: 28.02.2021

This returns the correctly filtered data for this date range. Then I change to another date range which works correctly as well. However, when I then try enter 01.01.2021 and 28.02.2021 as date range AGAIN, the filtered results contains random rows from the previously selected date range.

Is this a known problem or does anyone have an idea why this is happening?
The problem occurs with QUERY () and FILTER ().

Thanks
Niclas

Comment: Can you share the formula along with the data and you are using? Also, what are you expected to get? @NiclasBauer

Comment: =IF(OR($L$2="";$L$3="");"";FILTER(IMPORTRANGE(LinkMainList;"application!B2:B");IMPORTRANGE(LinkMainList;"application!P2:P")<>"";IMPORTRANGE(LinkMainList;"application!Q2:Q")="";(IMPORTRANGE(LinkMainList;"application!O2:O")="no")+(IMPORTRANGE(LinkMainList;"application!O2:O")="");IMPORTRANGE(LinkMainList;"application!R2:R")>=$L$2;IMPORTRANGE(LinkMainList;"application!R2:R")<=$L$3))

Comment: Can you share how does your data looks like and what you expect to receive as well? @NiclasBauer

Comment: Sorry. I would really like to share my spreadsheet, but it contains confidential data from my company. I will see if I finde the time to create a sample spreadsheet which reproduces the error.

Comment: I can only describe my data source: It's simply a long database containing columns Empl. ID, First Name, Last Name, Seniority, Unit, Location, Hiring Date. I am building a dashboard where a manager can go into another tab and just filter the data in the database tab by specifying start date and end date. The goal is to return the filtered dataset with only the rows where Hiring Date >= entered start date and Hiring Date <= end date.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your work so far but why not use QUERY() to "filter" using the WHERE clause instead.

```
WHERE date_column > date '2000-01-01' AND date_column < date '2010-01-01'
```

Taking this a step further, set two cells to hold the start and end dates and reference them in the QUERY() function SELECT statement

```
=QUERY(Data!$A$1:$H$136,"select C, B where B > date '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B < date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

In the above example A1 would hold the start date and B1 would hold the end date. By doing it this way you would never need to edit the formula, just change the values in the cells the formula references.

Comment: Hi John, i wrote my answer above. Was too long for comment section. It's really weird, because I used the same formula in another sheet and there switching dates did not produce the error. The sheet was also looking into the same other sheet (per Importrange) as the other sheet where the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's John. However, this is exactly what I did. I referenced both cells (start date and end date within my formula). I tried to filter the data with QUERY () (with WHERE clause) and I also tried doing it with FILTER () only. Both formula's produced the described error.

I will see if I can find the time to set up an example sheet, but meanwhile here the (i.m.o. unelegant) workaround solution that I used:

1: Filter the data using QUERY () or FILTER () with the selected dates. When switching dates I noticed that the result set always contained the correct data set (meaning the data for the currently selected dates) **PLUS** the random rows from the previously selected range.

2: I then filtered this table again for the currently selected dates using another filter formula and this worked fine and I got the data set for the selected date range WITHOUT the random rows. So I just filtered the filtered data set again.

Greetings
Niclas

Comment: Niclas, share the QUERY() function you wrote (not using FILTER() for now until you can post a sample sheet.